# Catch cmd window | Can I let it write to file by std?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe

Morning fellows,
I do have a tiny problem here. I have a Win10 machine and it behaves strangely. Well, it did it twice. I was just playing a game when it threw me out of the full screen application (minimized it) and opened a cmd prompt. There appeared roughly 16 lines and exited again.

It happened to me before, but I had a Steam download running in the background and I assumed it just installed dx or similar.

For now, I assume that's a legitimate prompt, but I really would love to catch it. So, what I want to do is to dump everything that cmd writes to stdout into a file. But I have little knowledge about windows. I know that this is possible by appending ">>" on a command, but I do not start those commands. Can I make it somehow cmd's standard behaviour? I really want to know what's up with that prompt.

Comment: Try looking at your event logs to see if windows captured any events during the times that this occurred.  Just go to your 'Ask me anything' prompt and type 'event log'.  There are several types of logs that show up in this area.  You will need to know when this even occurred.  Once you know this time frame, sift through the logs for any clues.

Comment: Sifting through? You're not joking... They did a whole lot to make it hard to show everything at once. In fact, it wasn't possible, but in the time the cmd prompt appeared, this happened: vc_runtimeAdditional_x64.msi

That's answering my question. Thank you a lot Dale. If you'd like, you could turn your comment into an answer so I could mark it as best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking at your event logs to see if windows captured any events during the times that this occurred. Just go to your 'Ask me anything' prompt and type 'event log'. There are several types of logs that show up in this area. You will need to know when this even occurred. Once you know this time frame, sift through the logs for any clues.